# Shoshin in regular buddhism

Tags: zen

In Zen-Buddhism there is the concept of the "Beginner's mind" called "[Sho Shin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoshin)" which I find fascinating. I haven't heard of something analogous in "regular" buddhism (meaning the forms of buddhism relating closer to the historic buddha). Does it exist and have a different name, or is it something that conflicts with the original teachings of the buddha?

Comment: There is a related question here about [beginners mind](http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/5128/157) which you may find interesting.

Answer (score 3):

the closest related thing i can think of is the teaching of overcoming mind tendency to objectification or conceptual proliferation (papañca), that is steering clear of preconceived concepts and notions about the world, reality and phenomena, which are dependent on our perception of those through the 6 sense organs, and disallowing ourselves to be obsessed with them

however this teaching in my view is much deeper because it aims immediately at the final goal, cessation of objectification is synonymous to attainment of nibbana

until then we need to learn to not fall victim to papañca and keep the mind in check